# How to loop through a text file using sbatch jobs

Tags: python, jobs, slurm, hpc, sbatch

I have a text file containing some lines of text and I want to pass each line of the file as an argument in my python script. The issue I'm having is reading the file. If I can read the file, I should be able to pass each line of the file as argument for my python job submission. here is what I've tried

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH -p RM-shared
#SBATCH -t 1:00:00
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=64


set file = \myfolder\sample.txt

for /f "tokens=*"  %%val in (%file%) do(
  echo %%val
  python3 test.py %%val
  )
```

When I run the batch submission of this job, and I check the slurm.out file, I see an error like this *"unexpected error near '"tokens=*"'

Please does anyone know how I can read from a text file and pass it as an argument in my python script?

Answer (score 0):

Slurm expect the syntax of the submission script to be a valid (Linux) shell script, typically Bash (hence the `shebang` you set as the first line). But your script does not use Bash syntax but rather Windows Batch script syntax.

The Bash interpreted is confused by the `%%` syntax ; hence the error message `"unexpected error near '"tokens="'`.

You will have to translate the script into valid Bash.